# Using fields as variable in views

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I'm not sure how to explain this in a good way, and my title may be way off.

I am using Views Data Export module and want to export a report for a specific user, and use his/hers name in the filename.

I have created a field in my user registration called "full name". Is there a way I can use this in my views etc. like for example "%full-name"? Any way I can achieve this?

I have tried to use "Report for [user:field-navn].doc", but then I get the filename "Report for [user:field-navn].doc" as filename, and not the name in it.

Comment: Depends, your view should be of user entity, if it is then field will be available in the field list, once the field is added the field table gets exposed to view and then later on you can use the token something like [your-field] later.

Comment: I have tried to specified even more. I have tried what you wrote @arpitr, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

as arpitr says, you need to include the field so that it becomes visible to Views. You can exclude it from view in the field settings if you don't want it to show - then try, borrowed from (adjust appropriately for your setup) [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1485602):

> It's not super-obvious how to do this, but it is pretty easy.
>
> The downloaded filename has nothing to do with the "path" in the "data
>   export settings" - that is simply the path that is used to trigger the
>   generation of the file.
>
> To set the actual filename, click "settings" next to "CSV file" in the
>   View's "format" section. Then, check the "provide as file" box and
>   then set the filename (including token) there.